# ActionScript 2 not loading movie on first click

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

This is my code when the user click on a button to load a movie.

```
on(release)
{
    loadMovie("pages/Page8.swf", 2);                        
}
```

You have to click on the button twice for the movie to start playing.
What am I missing?

Comment: not loading or not start playing the movie or should be both done

Comment: It only start playing on the second click.

Answer (score 0):

you schould `.play()` on MovieClip,

`loadMovie` lets you display several movies at once and switch between them.

Comment: I am not following, where must I place this .play() exactly?

Comment: what is your `2` ? Is this a MovieClip ? like `loadMovie("pages/Page8.swf", _root.myMovieClip);` then `myMovieClip.play()`